I am unable to remove sprinkles from inner part of icing for donut by using weight paint
So I was watching this blender guide
https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEPv5y--4MKpciLaoQYZB1Z&si=mfyfhlZThtu0CTSy
And teacher said that i should remove sprinkles from inner part of icing to save time for rendering.
1 I enabled weight paint mode.
2 Enabled check mark for "Front faces only"
3 Accepted all modifiers
But when i draw on outer side of icing it still also draws on inner side of icing.
Can you please help me find solution for my problem?

Hello, are you sure that your object has thickness? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

It seems the object has thickness, judging by the sculpted drips and rim.  I'd go for face orientation issues (in edit mode, select all a and shift+n). ---- But this seems indeed like a classical "no thickness" issue, that happens when you try to paint before "apply" (an action with this name) the solidify modifier.



Here is my blend file

Your object has no thickness, if you weight paint on a side it will paint on the opposite side. If you want thickness you can give a Solidify modifier to your object or select all and AltE > Extrude Faces Along Normals, make sure that the normals are correctly oriented (select all in Edit mode and ShiftN) and paint in Weight Paint mode (make sure that the Front Faces Only option is activated):

